# Are the article types configurable and will there be support for attachments?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

If I upgrade to Business (for Stack Overflow for Teams) are the article types configurable?  I noticed in your documentation I see a standard set like "Knowledge Article", "Policy" and a couple more. I was curious if these types can be created?

Also I am close to wanting to get rid of Confluence because it's so buggy. What's stopping me is the fact that in Confluence I can add attachments to say a page (an article). Is there a plan to one day allow for attachments to say an article? And an article may have multiple attachments associated with it. So essentially you could have a collection with many articles and many questions/answers. I almost think in your documentation you should place collections above both questions and articles since it's the feature that brings these things together? https://stackoverflow.com/teams/tour shows collections being third when it seems it should be at the top.